# Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure in AWS lamdba selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, aws-lambda-layers

- Java 11
- Selenium (4.11.0 dependancy added in lamdba)
- AWS lamdba (Runtime java 11)

Below code inside the lamdba handler

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromedriver");

WebDriver driver = null;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();


prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);


options.setBinary("/opt/headless-chromium");
options.addArguments("--headless=new");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--single-process");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

     driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.manage().window().maximize();
log.info("Created Chrome Browser");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(1000));
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/simple_context_menu.html");
log.info("=========>" + driver.getTitle());
```

Getting the above issue while we deploy above code in AWS lambda, Added the `Headless-chromium` & `chromedriver` as layer to lambda, but still we are getting: `Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure`

Did we miss anything here?

Comment: For more info : I am trying to run  above program using Selenium chrome driver in aws lamdba console.